# TypeError with mixed dtypes when plotting a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dtype

I try the basic seaborn example and it works:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
sns.set(style="whitegrid")
tips = sns.load_dataset("tips")
sns.violinplot(ax=ax, x="day", y="total_bill", data=tips)
```

I try to write something similar on a dataframe I created myself:

```
names = np.array(["Class 1", 'Class 2'])
aa = names[np.random.randint(0,2,100)]
bb = np.random.uniform(0,1,100)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.array([aa, bb]).T, columns=["key", "value"])
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
sns.violinplot(ax=ax, data=df, x="key", y="value")
```

and it throws a long error, ending in:

```
/opt/anaconda3/envs/py36nest/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/core/_methods.py in _mean(a, axis, dtype, out, keepdims)
     76     if isinstance(ret, mu.ndarray):
     77         ret = um.true_divide(
---> 78                 ret, rcount, out=ret, casting='unsafe', subok=False)
     79         if is_float16_result and out is None:
     80             ret = arr.dtype.type(ret)

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'int'
```

What the hell am I doing wrong? The dataframe looks correct when I display it

**EDIT**: I have found that if I construct my DataFrame in a different way, it works without error

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"key" : aa, "value" : bb})
```

whyyyyy????

Comment: should `aa` just be `np.random.randint(0,2,100)`?

Comment: @Andrew I am making a categorical variable that can have 2 values - "Class 1" and "Class 2". It works as expected with categorical variables in the seaborn examples

Comment: That's a weird way to do it, just use `aa = np.random.choice(names, 100)`

Comment: @ChrisA It's not weird if you don't know `np.random.choice` exists :D

Comment: Also, numpy arrays are homogenous (essentially have 1 dtype), so `np.array([aa, bb])` is casting that dtype to be `object` or "str" if you like - including your random int values. Check out `df.info()` to see. Where as the `dict` method in your edit, each array is being treated independently, one as object, the other as int

Comment: @ChrisA yes, it seems to be as simple as that :(

Comment: Avoid using `np.array` in pandas when constructing dataframes, you can't control your dtype. Also, this has nothing specifically to do with seaborn or violinplot, can you fix the title?

Comment: Re: *"a long error, something about trying to calculate the mean"*. Read what the error message is saying more closely. The last line tells you clearly it hiccups on your data series mixing 'str' and 'int' dtypes - it just so happens that occurred inside a numpy mean function - but it could have been anything. The important lesson is you stop and start investigating the dtypes in your own dataframe - which has nothing to do with seaborn or violinplot.

Comment: Yes, numpy and pandas stacktraces tend to be long and confusing. You need to figure out how to zero in on the telltale part. Usually that's the bottom, sometimes it's the top.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways to solve your problem or answer your question, but I will present three methods.

Like you thought, your main problem is with how you are creating your dataframe, specifically how you are calling `np.array` inside the `DataFrame()`, which is converting the entire array to one `dtype`. Like other users have mentioned, you can circumvent this by either using `pandas Series`, list comprehension, or the dictionary format you are using.

Each of the following works for me:

**Method 1: Series**

```
names = np.array(["Class 1", 'Class 2'])
aa = names[np.random.randint(0,2,100)]
bb = np.random.uniform(0,1,100)
# df = pd.DataFrame(np.array([aa, bb]).T, columns=["key", "value"]) #YOUR OLD CODE

#USING SERIES (slowest but easiest to understand)
aa_series = pd.Series(aa, name = 'key') #the name of the series can turn into column names (or index names depending on method of concatenation)
bb_series = pd.Series(bb, name = 'value')

df = pd.DataFrame([aa_series,bb_series]).T #transpose to match a realistic format


fig, ax = plt.subplots()
sns.violinplot(ax=ax, data=df, x="key", y="value")
```

**Method 2: List Comprehension**

```
names = np.array(["Class 1", 'Class 2'])
aa = names[np.random.randint(0,2,100)]
bb = np.random.uniform(0,1,100)
# df = pd.DataFrame(np.array([aa, bb]).T, columns=["key", "value"]) #YOUR OLD CODE

#USING LIST COMPREHENSION (faster, not as easy to get)

data = [[aa[i],bb[i]] for i in range(len(aa))] #put the data into 2 cols "manually"
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=["key", "value"]) 

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
sns.violinplot(ax=ax, data=df, x="key", y="value")
```

**Method 3: dictionary method**
The update you presented.

Personally, I find the `Series` method easiest to follow and work with pandas, but all three should yield you the result you seek.